# How to define parameter type 1 to be keyof interface and parameter type 2 to be the corresponding value of the interface key

Tags: typescript

I have this interface

```
export interface TriggerType {
    'sp:assign-topics:success': _CardGroup[],
    'one': string,
    'two': number,
}
```

And then this class.

```
export class TriggerHelper {
    public static trigger(type: keyof TriggerType, data?: TriggerType[typeof type]) {
        if (data === undefined) {
            data = null;
        }
        // jQuery(window).trigger(type, data);
        window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(type, {detail: data}));
    }

    public static on(type: keyof TriggerType, callback: (data: TriggerType[typeof type]) => void) {

    }
}
```

For the `trigger` method, I want the `type` to be `keyof` that interface and the value to be the `valueof` the corresponding `key` of the interface.

I also **don't** want to provide **generic** parameters for the trigger function for 2 reasons

- I don't want to provide it every time I call `trigger()` as I want it to be centralized.
- Its also needed in the `on()` function, for the callback data type. So that whoever will call `on()` will know exactly the `type` of `data` based on the `type` they are listening to.

What I have right now allows this

```
TriggerHelper.trigger('one', 43);
TriggerHelper.trigger('two', 'hi');
```

which is not what I need.

#### After thought

It looks like generics is the only way to go. I was avoiding using it in this case but apparently, there is no way else to do it.

Comment: You say you don't want generics but I don't understand your reasons.  What specifically about [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m0VGPw) doesn't work for you?

Comment: Sure. It appears this was the only way. Already have it in place except I was always providing the generics whenever I call them. Turns out it wasn't necessary as they'll be inferred if I don't.

Comment: I guess you wrote up your own answer here, which is fine, but I'm wondering if you could maybe [edit] the question and answer so that it doesn't include requirements you don't actually have.  The "I don't want generics" seems like an XY problem (or maybe its inverse: user wants to do X but has decided that they *don't* want to do Y), since you've excluded the only reasonable solution for reasons that don't apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the only way to achieve this in Typescript today is by using Generics which I didn't want to use originally to avoid having to provide the generic parameter multiple times.

```
export class TriggerHelper {
    /**
     *
     * @param type
     * @param data The corresponding value of the key in TriggerType.
     */
    public static trigger<T extends keyof TriggerType>(type: T, data?: TriggerType[T]) {
        if (data === undefined) {
            debugger;
            data = null;
        }
        window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(type, {detail: data}));
    }

    public static on<T extends keyof TriggerType>(type: T, callback: (e: any, data: TriggerType[T]) => void) {
        window.addEventListener(type, (e: any) => {
            callback(e, e.detail);
        });
    }

    public static off<T extends keyof TriggerType>(type: T, callback: (e: any, data: TriggerType[T]) => void) {
        window.removeEventListener(type, (e: any) => {
            callback(e, e.detail);
        });
    }
}
```

However, it turns out generics are also inferred when Typescript can [Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#hello-world-of-generics) and that was helpful here. So I didn't need to provide the generic parameters all the time even though they were defined in the methods.
Also rightly pointed out by @jonrsharpe in the comments.